# For the following linear mapping, determine a transformation matrix and check for the property of injectivity.

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, finite-fields

I have the following exam question:

In the $\mathbb{F_3}$ vector space $V:= M(2,2,\mathbb{F_3})$ of $2 \times 2$ matrices, the following linear mapping $\varphi$ is given:

$\varphi : V \rightarrow V, A \mapsto A + A^T$

a) Determine a basis B of $V: M(2,2,\mathbb{F_3})$.

b) Determine the transformation matrix $M_B^B(\varphi)$

c) Determine if the matrix D $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is in the image space $im(\varphi)$ of $\varphi$.

d) Determine if the mapping is injective.

---

Progress so far:

a)

Calculating $\varphi(A)$ where $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ yields:

$\varphi (\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b + c \\ b + c & d \end{pmatrix}$ which can be identified as the set of symmetric $2\times2$ matrices. Letting $b + c = e$, it can be seen that the following set of 3 matrices forms a spanning set and thus a basis for V:

$B = \{ b_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, b_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},  b_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\}$

As a consequence of this, it nescessarily follows that **c)** will be contained in the image (Calculations have been ommited here, but to answer this question more rigorously one might solve the coeffecients $a_{1,2,3}$ such that  $a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3 = D$.

At this point I become lost. Can anyone provide some assistance for steps b) and d)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the vector space you have is isomorphic to vectors with $4$ entries, so your basis should have $4$ elements (to see the isomorphism, just map the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ onto $(a,b,c,d)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Your answer is wrong. A basis of a $4$-dimensional space must have $4$ elements. You can take, for instance, $b_1=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, $b_2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$,  $b_3=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, and $b_4=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

b) The matrix you're after will be then$$\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}.$$

d) No. For instance, $\varphi\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Or you can see that the determinant of the matrix from b) is $0$.

Comment: Thanks, your feedback is very helpful. 

Would you mind elaborating a little bit on how you determined the matrix in part b?

Comment: @Oscar It follows from the fact that $\varphi(b_1)=b_1+b_1^T=2b_1$, $\varphi(b_2)=b_2+b_2^T=b_2+b_3$, $\varphi(b_3)=b_3+b_3^T=b_3+b_2$, and $\varphi(b_4)=b_4+b_4^T=2b_4$.